# (css) next image undergoes transition while using div:hover in a grid

Tags: html, css

I used grid to order layout in a page. When I do hover effect to the img, in a div, it kinda breaks so I don't want to do it.

After I tried hover effect on the whole div, however this time when I hover over div it transforms other div's image. What causes this and how to solve it?

HTML

```
<div class="content1" id="webpages">
            <div class="cards" id="card1">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x168/000/ffffff&text=dummy+box1" alt="webpage unavaliable">
            </div>
            <div class="cards" id="card2">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x168/000/ffffff&text=dummy+box2" alt="webpage unavaliable">
            </div>
            <div class="cards" id="card3">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x168/000/ffffff&text=dummy+box3" alt="webpage unavaliable">
            </div>
            <div class="cards" id="card4">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x168/000/ffffff&text=dummy+box4" alt="webpage unavaliable">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
/* Cards layout Starts Here */

.cards {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cards img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.cards:hover+.cards img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22%;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 298px;
}

.cards #plus {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

/* Cards layout Ends Here */

/* Grids Starts Here */

.content1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 20px;
}

/* Grids Ends Here */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong css selector, instead of **.cards:hover+.cards img** should be **.cards:hover img**

Comment: `.cards:hover+.cards img` means "select a <img> element within an element of class .cards that follows a class .cards that is being hovered"